# Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined

Tags: node.js

I'm writing a nodejs application.

I'm trying to use the async plugin to connect, query and disconnect from db.

the 'class' that I created is the following:

```
var config = ini.parse(fs.readFileSync('config/config.ini', 'utf-8'));
var mysql = require('mysql');

var inspect = require('util').inspect;
module.exports = TuxDb;

function TuxDb() {
    this._connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: config.db.host,
    user: config.db.username,
    password: config.db.password,
    database: config.db.schema
});
}

TuxDb.prototype.connect = function (callback) {
 this._connection.connect(function (err) {
    callback(err, null);
 });
}
```

and the code:

```
var TuxDb = require('../../db/db.js');
var tuxDB = new TuxDb();
  async.series([tuxDB.connect,
    function (callback) {
        tuxDB.getGenericDrinks(callback);
    }, function (callback) {
        tuxDB.disconnect(null, callback);
    }
], function (err, result) {
    if (err != null) {
        return next(new restify.InvalidArgumentErrror(err));
    }
});
```

i get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined
```

I don't quite understand why. the constructor already sets `this._connection` so why in the connect function `this._connection` is null?

Comment: Maybe because `mysql.createConnection` returned null?

Comment: i checked. it returns an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you passed a function to `async.series`, thus causing it to lose context. `this` when it is executed will not be the instance. To fix it, use `.bind` to ensure the context stays.

```
async.series([tuxDB.connect.bind(tuxDB),
```

Another alternative would be to pass an anonymous function.

```
async.series([function (next) {
  tuxDB.connect(next);
},
```